# Check permission always return denied

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I was asking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission with the following statement

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), PERMISSION_WRITE)
```

This was working...until now. In the method `onRequestPermissionsResult`, `grantResults` always contains -1

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_WRITE) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Timber.i("PERMISSION GRANTED")
        } else {

            showSettingsDialog()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have the uses-permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The thing is, if I go to the app settings the permission appears as granted but from the app it always return is not granted.

I tried deleting build folders because none has changed and this was working fine for a week

Any idea about what can I test?

best regards

Comment: Do you call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` from the same activity/fragment that you override `onRequestPermissionsResult`?

Comment: @Zain yes, in the main activity

Comment: Did you request `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  in manifest?

Comment: @Zain yes, and im testing on Android 10

Comment: Can you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>` to the manifest instead

Comment: @Zain, ok now its working. What i dont understand at all is why it stopped working as i added no changes in graddle or in the manifest.

Please, post the answer an i will accept it.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug in android 10, so you can replace the permission in manifest with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```